How to sign out from Skype app on Android?
When I (or somebody) tap on the Skype app on my Android phone, Skype opens signed in and shows all my messages. How do I get rid of this? That ism I want the Skype app on Android to ask the password each time it is opened. I  have reasons not to want to password-protect (with unlock code) the whole phone. I  only want to password protect the Skype app on it.
I tried rebooting the phone, but Skype  keeps remembering me and opening my messages.  I want it to forget me once and forever. I have not tried uninstallng it and reinstalling: I don't want to lose all my history.
Mcrosoft's own  instructions say:

Tap or click your profile picture.

Select Sign out.


But  when  I tap my picture or name at the top of the Skype app window, above the list of my  contacts (chats, messages) immediately after the app opened, a page opens with many things, such as Invite Friends, etc.but no Sign out item is there. Where is it?

I saw Sign out at the bottom of the menu. Could you list what you see?
